# Confused by warning when using the "dot dot prefix" (..) in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to sum some columns in a data.table, specifying those columns in a variable. I then use the `..` prefix (see [New Features `data.table` 1.10.2](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-v1102--31-jan-2017)) to select those columns. However, this results in a Warning:

```
mdt <- as.data.table(mtcars)
factorsGEN <- c("disp","hp","drat")
# This works but gives the warning below
mdt[ , score := rowSums(mdt[ , ..factorsGEN])]
#Warning message:
#  In `[.data.table`(mdt, , ..factorsGEN) :
#  Both 'factorsGEN' and '..factorsGEN' exist in calling scope. Please remove 
# the '..factorsGEN' variable in calling scope for clarity.

# This does not work, results in error because factorsGEN is not found
mdt[, score := rowSums(mdt[, factorsGEN])]
```

I get a warning, which I don't remember getting when I first wrote the code, so it may be the result of an update to the data.table code.  Could anyone please tell me how to avoid the warning.  I can't figure it out.

Comment: This is an [open issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2988)

Comment: Thank you Henrik for pointing that out.  I guess I can safely ignore the warnings for now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use .SD and the warning vanishes.

```
mdt[ , score := rowSums(mdt[ , .SD, .SDcols = factorsGEN])]
```